# Tinyscroll plugin, scroll both the container div along with the dropdown menu

Tags: jquery

I have a container div with tinyscrollbar enabled. In that container div i also have a dropdown menu which is customized by tiny scrollbar plugin. Now when i try to mouse scroll the dropdown menu, even the container content is also scrolling. how to scroll only the dropdown menu?

Answer (score 0):

There is a option in tinyscrollbar that is called scroll. If you turn that off scrolling with a mousewheel will stop working.